# How to use pool processing to update global dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing, global-variables

I'm trying to use pool processing of Python to update global dictionary named: globalDict. I'm expecting that the globalDict={'0':0,'1':1,'2':2} but after the code run, this dictionary is still blank. Please help me to fix this issue, the code as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    global globalDict # update this dictionary every time function called
    globalDict.setdefault(str(x),x)
    return globalDict

def init_pool(dictX):
    # function to initial global dictionary 
    global globalDict
    globalDict = dictX

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start=time.time()
    globalDict={}
    pool=Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(globalDict,)) # initial global dictionary
    pool.map(f, range(3)) # using pool processing to call f()function
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    stop=time.time()
    print('Done in {:4f}'.format(stop-start))
```

Comment: Assign a variable to the method calling because here your code is return the processed globalDict and try to print that variable to check the variable like the below code
 
result = pool.map(f, range(3))
print(result)

Comment: Remember that each multiprocessing instance is running its own process with its own memory space.  There are no "globals" across processes.  You can use a `Queue` to return data from one process to another.

Comment: Thanks @Nireekshan for your reply. What I need is the global dictionary globalDict has to be updated. The result of calling function is the list of dictionary only: [{'0': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'2': 2}]

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. The pool processing is very new to me, can you please provide more detail about Queue

Comment: Look up `multiprocessing.queue`.  It is an interprocess tunnel.  One process shoves things in one end, another process pulls things out the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use a *managed* dictionary. There is no need to be returning the dictionary back from the worker function, `f`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import time

def f(x):
    globalDict.setdefault(str(x),x)

def init_pool(dictX):
    # function to initial global dictionary
    global globalDict
    globalDict = dictX

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    with Manager() as manager:
        globalDict = manager.dict()
        pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(globalDict,)) # initial global dictionary
        pool.map(f, range(3)) # using pool processing to call f()function
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        stop = time.time()
        print('Done in {:4f}'.format(stop-start))
        print(globalDict)
```

Prints:

```
Done in 0.606996
{'0': 0, '2': 2, '1': 1
```

If you want to end up with a "regular" dictionary that no longer requires the `SycnManager` class that is returned by the call to `Manager()`, then after the call to `map` completes, add the following statement:

```py
regular_dict = {k: v for k, v in globalDict.items()}
```

Or, if you want to get clever, you can create your own managed dictionary type (we will call it `Dict`) that only supports the one method we need, `setdefault`, and dispatches that method call to an underlying `dict` that we will be able to retrieve when our call to `map` completes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time

class DictManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class Dict:
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {}

    def setdefault(self, *args):
        return self._dict.setdefault(*args)

    def get_underlying_dict(self):
        return self._dict

def f(x):
    globalDict.setdefault(str(x),x)

def init_pool(dictX):
    # function to initial global dictionary
    global globalDict
    globalDict = dictX

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    DictManager.register('Dict', Dict)
    with DictManager() as manager:
        globalDict = manager.Dict()
        pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(globalDict,)) # initial global dictionary
        pool.map(f, range(3)) # using pool processing to call f()function
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        stop = time.time()
        print('Done in {:4f}'.format(stop-start))
        regular_dict = globalDict.get_underlying_dict()
    print(regular_dict)
```

Prints:

```
Done in 0.460001
{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Booboo, it works perfectly. However I need more time to digest all your ideas. One thing I don't understand why in solution 1 (not used regular dictionary), the output is exactly what I want, but after the code run, I run command print(globalDict) again, but the result is <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x23cd2a3efd0; '__str__()' failed>

Comment: A managed dictionary such as `globalDict` is represented by a proxy object.  When you invoke a method on it, in this case `__str__` to get a string representation of it to print it, it actually results in the equivalent of a remote procedure call to a server process that was started when `with Manager() as manager:` was executed (on Linux communications to the server is done via a socket and on Windows via a named Pipe). When the `with` block terminates, so does the server process and you can therefore no longer make calls on the proxy object. BTW, the server can be on a different machine.

Comment: I got it. Thanks @Booboo a lot for your detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will get expected output as : {0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2'}

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    global globalDict # update this dictionary every time function called
    globalDict.setdefault(str(x),x)
    return globalDict

def init_pool(dictX):
    # function to initial global dictionary 
    global globalDict
    globalDict = dictX

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start=time.time()
    globalDict={}
    pool=Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(globalDict,)) # initial global dictionary
    result = pool.map(f, range(3)) # using pool processing to call f()function
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    stop=time.time()
    print('Done in {:4f}'.format(stop-start))
    for i in result:
        res = {val : key for key, val in i.items()}
    print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks again @Nireekshan, you code is only return the last item of the result ({'2':2}). I can manage to update the list of dictionary to new dictionary in this case, however as I said earlier I need my globalDict to be updated because in my real case, this dictionary is very complex like: {'type1':{'node':{'sector1':{'parameter1': value}}}, 'type2':{'relation':{'node':'sector1':{'neighbor1':{'parameter2':value}}}}}